# How to interpret that "${\cal E}(Y|X)$ is a function of $X$"?

Tags: statistics

> this function is a random variable. It is a probability distribution and therefore an expected value given $x$.

Comment: Just like is said. If you assign $X$ a value, $E(U|X)$ takes a well defined value.

Comment: But what about Y? given X, we don't know Y

Comment: The expectation is taken over all possible values.

Comment: perfect! thanks!

Comment: Please don't change the notation after comments have been written.